# Getting the properties of an item through web services

Tags: 2013, web-services, splistitem, rest, properties

Is it possible to get the [SPListItem.Properties property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.properties.aspx) of an item through one of the out-of-the-box API web services in SP 2013?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do it through Lists web service, GetListItems method: [Lists.GetListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

This method will return result in xml format that will contain ows_MetaInfo attribute that will have all SPListItem.Properties.